# One-way hashing using singular matrices?

Tags: encryption, hash, password-hashing, matrix-multiplication

In matrix encoding, we convert our message into some numerical value and then create a matrix out of those numbers.
The matrice encryption is based on the fact that a matrix multiplied by its inverse is a unity matrix, so, if we pre-multiply a marix by some encoding matrix $X$ it will get encrypted and will be decoded only by pre-multiplying the encrypted matrix with $X^{-1}$.
But, what will be the case if the encoding matrix is singular ie. $|X|=0$, Then $X^{-1}$ does not exist because $X^{-1}=\frac{1}{|X|}adj(x)$.
So, it wouldn't be possible to get original matrix even if we know the encoding matrix.

**Does it mean that the message is encrypted forever. If not, How to decode it? and if yes, Is it universal hashing?**

Comment: This sounds like a very bad linear hashing scheme. Almost as bad as a linear congruential random number generator.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is not invertible, then your encryption operation is not injective.  That is, there exist messages m1 and m2 that are not equal but for which E(m1) = E(m2).  If you receive c = E(m1), it is not possible to uniquely determine the original message.  Recall that it's possible to characterize all messages that will encrypt to the same value; for any k in the kernel, E(m + k) = E(m).

I'm deliberately avoiding any analysis of the security of this scheme.

Comment: But if we use bigger matrices, such possibility is very less